# Can Firebase transform data server-side before writing it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

According to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#perform_database_sanitization_and_maintenance), and [this accompanying example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/text-moderation), Firebase tends to follow the following flow when transforming newly written data:

1. Client writes data to Firebase, which is immediately accepted
2. The supplied Cloud Function is triggered, which transforms the data (in the example above, it removes swear words)
3. The transformed data is written again, overwriting the original data written in step 1

Maybe I'm missing something here, but this flow seems to present some problems.  For example, if there is an error in step 2 above, and step 3 is never fired, the un-transformed data will just linger in the database.  It seems like it would be better to transform the data as soon as it hits the server, but before writing.  This would be followed by a single write operation, which will leave no loose artifacts behind if it fails.  Is there any way in the current Firebase + Google Cloud Functions stack to add these types of pre-write data transforms?

My (tentative and weird) solution so far is to have a "shadow" `/_temp/{endpoint}` area in my Firebase db, so that when I want to write to `/{endpoint}`, I write there instead, which then triggers the relevant cloud function to do the transformation before writing to `/{endpoint}`.  This at least prevents potentially incomplete data from leaking into my database, but it seems very inelegant and "hacky."

I'd also be interested to know if there are any server-side methods for transforming data before responding to read requests.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hook in the Firebase Database (neither through Cloud Functions nor elsewhere) that allows you to modify values before they're written to the database. The temporary queue is the idiomatic way to address this use-case. It functions pretty similar to a moderator queue in most forum software.

You could use a HTTP Function to create an endpoint that your code calls and then perform the transformation there. You could use a similar pattern for reading data, although you'd have to rebuild the realtime synchronization capabilities of Firebase yourself.

Comment: I've ended up doing pretty much this.  We're using firebase more for its out of the box scaling than its real time capabilities, so this seems like a good fit!